# How to implement an interface to a List object

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface

Ok, the question is really general. I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IGizmo<T>
```

and a class implementing the interface

```
public class A:IGizmo<A>
```

How can I implement the interface

```
IGizmo<List<A>>
```

on objects of the form:

```
List<A> L
```

Or if the above is not possible, is there a "natural way" to implement an interface to a list object class from an interface defined on the class?

Comment: Since `List` is not under your control, this isn't possible. The question is probably too generic (pardon the expression) -- the construction `A : IGizmo<A>` is an unusual one with typically very specific use cases (like `IEquatable<T>`) and it's hard to say what the right way to "fix" things is without knowing what you're using it for. (To consider the parallel with `IEquatable<T>`, there is no concept of an "equatable list" as such, but then there is `IStructuralEquatable` and `StructuralComparisons`, which achieves the underlying goal.)

Comment: You can, for example, have a method taking an `IEnumerable<T> where T : IGizmo<T>`, requiring that not the collection but the item implements a particular interface; a `List<A>` would then satisfy this constraint. If you really want, you can introduce a wrapper type specifically to implement `IGizmo<MyWrapper<T>>` for any enumerable or list type, by delegation.

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind, or are you just asking out of curiosity? For the former, it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For the latter, the answer would be: no. You cannot change `List<T>`, so you cannot let it implement new interfaces. Also, why (only?) `List<T>`? What about arrays (`T[]`)? Or anything else that implements the `IList<T>` interface? Or `ICollection<T>`? Or even `IEnumerable<T>`? `List<T>` is just _one_ implementation of "a bunch of T" with a very specific set of rules.

Comment: @Corak yes  curiosity and also trying to understand how the language works (what are these objects intensions, what actually  an interface is etc)

Comment: Since `List` in particular is available for subclassing, you can have `class GizmoList<T> : List<T>, IGizmo<List<T>> where T : IGizmo<T> {} `. Whether that's meaningful in your scenario is another matter,  though, and this works for `List` specifically because you can inherit from it (which is not the case for all collection types).

Comment: @Squaresharper - Curiosity is awesome! But sometimes an idea turns out to not be possible/feasible. As for what interfaces are, they are usually described as "contracts". For some time I misunderstood a class implementing an interface as that class saying: "look what I can do!". Now, I see it the other way round. If a method accepts an interface as parameter, the method is saying: "look what I **need**!". The method doesn't care about the actual implementation, it just needs _something_ with the right properties/methods to do its thing. And that need is communicated as an interface.

Comment: @Corak -This is really true. Thank you for the tip. I think it is a very good thing to have in mind when using an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is a Generic interface, your implementation could be:

```
public class ObjectWithoutList : IGizmo<A>

public class ObjectWithList : IGizmo<List<A>>
```

Without more context I believe you've misunderstood generics? If not could you give more info?

Otherwise see these links for more info on Generics:

[Pluralsight Course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-generics?aid=701j0000001heIpAAI&promo=&oid=&utm_source=non_branded&utm_medium=digital_paid_search_google&utm_campaign=UK_Dynamic&utm_content=&gclid=CjwKCAiA98TxBRBtEiwAVRLqu97g3TERjVQbcx3XD-QC5p-YFI8fDoMNKgisezOeshwgnzpth-ZWVhoCmhcQAvD_BwE)

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: I think your answer is in the correct direction. What I want to test is if something like the following can be made: `public class A : IGizmo<A>` `public class List<A> : IGizmo<List<A>>` I don't know if something like this makes sense (forgive me but i am a primer in oop and c#)

Comment: @Squaresharper - For that, you would either need to change the implementation of `List<T>` (which you can't, as Jeroen explained), or you would need to create your own "List" class, where the question would be: why? Why would you want to do that, or are you [misunderstanding what a list is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)?